# REST: same endpoint for a resource with different conditional parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Let's assume I have an endpoint called

```
/people
```

which, as the name suggests, returns a set of people. Instead of returning "all" people, the requestor can add a request parameter "q" which can have two possible syntax (say S1 and S2).

- S1 will trigger a specific logic which is completely different from S2
- S1 accepts a set of request parameters {P1S1, P2S1, P3S1}
- S2 accepts a set of request parameters {P1S2, P2S2, P3S2} which has nothing to do with the S1 set

I could have a signature like this:

```
public Page<Person> people(@RequestParam String q, String p1s1, String p2s1, ..., String p2s2, String p3s2) {
 if (q contains S1 syntax)
   ...
 else (q contains S2 syntax)
   ... 
}
```

depending on the value of q I could check the subsequent parameters and execute the corresponding search logic. My doubt is that the interface in that case wouldn't be formally explicated. In other words, looking at the interface it's not clear which parameter is required when.

Is there a correct way to model/implement that scenario?

Comment: If the two sets of input parameters are also associated with different querying behavior, and different results, then I might suggest just having two endpoints.

Comment: what could be the name of those endpoints? Both should be "/people" because the are returning the same exact representation of the same exact entity. I would just move the interface ambiguity from parameters to endpoint names

Comment: I can't really answer to your comment in a meaningful way without knowing the real endpoint and parameters.

Comment: Ok, q = the query string, (results offset + page size in case of S1), (highlight, fuzzy, multilanguage in case of S2)

Comment: Doesn't Spring have annotations to make parameters optional? In any case, I think you can go with either option here.

Comment: First design problem in terms of REST: you already consider that `/people` will return people specific data and therefore have a [typed resource](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). Second problem: you treat the endpoint as an RPC method invocation instead of a resource

Comment: Optional<String> to make em optional. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @Jeff I'm not talking about Java's `Optional`, I'm referring to Spring's `@RequestParam(required = false)`

Comment: @RomanVottner I didn't get you...the endpoint is returning a list of people. How would you express in REST "give me a list of people?" I understand that behind the scenes there must be something like "searchPeople" but from the interface perspective I understand I need a GET on the person resource in order to fetch the corresponding representation

Comment: Guys, optional or required=false doesn't answer to my question If I follow that approach, then I would code a single method with 1 required parameter and all the others optional. And that is ok, but my question is: how can the client understand that the first 2 parameters are used only when q follows the S1 syntax (and the other 3 used when q follows S2 syntax)?

Comment: @RomanVottner thanks for that nice pointer, very appreciated. But I think it doesn't help so much in addressing my "pragmatic" example. What I read is more on a theoretical plan, where everything "should ideally be in this and that way". My need is a bit more concrete. Unless I completely misunderstood the REST paradigm (and it is possible, of course) what I'm trying to do doesn't sound to me it is terribly violating that paradigm